# Why is the prefix in my citation not working?

Tags: citing, memoir, languages, apa6

When I try to make a prefix, it breaks the command. I have tried both the `\citep,` `\citet` and the `\cite` commands. I have also tried looking at the Babel files, and changing the '<' and '>' to '<<' and '>>' in the commands:

`\declare@shorthand{danish}{"<}{\textormath{\guillemotleft}{\mbox{\guillemotleft}}}`
`\declare@shorthand{danish}{">}{\textormath{\guillemotright}{\mbox{\guillemotright}}}`

But that did not work. Postfixes works fine.

```
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@article{smiths,
  author  = {Smith, A.},
  journal = {Journal of Apacite},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {24305--36811},
  title   = {{How do I prefix?}},
  volume  = {1},
  year    = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\renewcommand{\danishhyphenmins}{22}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{document}
\section{Citations}
\citep<The prefix is not working>[Postfix works fine]{smiths}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know, the syntax is `\citep[prefix][postfix]{key}`

Comment: That was easy... I looked in the apacite manual and it says multiple places that `\cite<prefix>[postfix]{key}` is the correct syntax. So thank you for correcting me, and the manual :0D

Comment: The manual is correct, but you should check on page 15, section 4.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not working because you're using the wrong syntax:

```
\citep[Prefix][Postfix]{key}
\citet[Prefix][Postfix]{key}
```

(don't use `\cite`, although it's the same as `\citep`).

If you just want a prefix, use an empty second optional argument:

```
\citep[Prefix][]{key}
\citet[Prefix][]{key}
```

Just one optional argument will use it as postfix:

```
\citep[Postfix]{key}
\citet[Postfix]{key}
```

Note that this is because you're using the `natbibapa` option. See section 4.2 of the manual, page 15.